# How to show hint text in Java Graphics2D

Tags: java, graphics

I am wondering if it is possible to show a "hint text" on mouseover in Java Graphics2d. something like:

```
Graphics2D      g; 
g.fillRect(0, 0, w, h); 
g.showhint("Show this hint if mouse is over the area:",0,0,10,20); ?????
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're referring to some arbitrary *painted* text, then sure:

- Add a mouse-listener that records when the curser enters or leaves the desired area.
- Let the listener set a boolean variable according to the events
- Whenever the boolean changes, call `repaint()`
- Let the paint-method paint the hint if the boolean is set.

---

If you're referring to **tooltips**: Yes, it is possible too.

Here is an excerpt from [the official tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/tooltip.html):

> *Even in components that have no API for setting part-specific tool tip text, you can generally do the job yourself. If the component supports renderers, then you can set the tool tip text on a custom renderer. The table and tree sections provide examples of tool tip text determined by a custom renderer. An alternative that works for all `JComponents` is creating a subclass of the component and overriding its `getToolTipText(MouseEvent)` method.*

The latter approach seems even trivial to implement.